# Get files from a folder and save to database with Python

Tags: python

How to get all files from a folder and store it using python ?
This code finds the files

```
# list of dir

list_of_dir = os.listdir(dir_loc)
print(list_of_dir)
```

How can i store these files ?
The file types can be jpeg, png, txt , csv . I need to upload all files in to database ( mongodb )

Comment: What does "store" mean in this context?

Comment: saving in database, well posting in database is not a problem, but how i can get all files ? should i post `list_of_dir`

Comment: `os.listdir(dir_loc)` gives you all the files. I really don't understand the question one bit.

Comment: i need to get all the files from a folder and post it in database, with that code i can find the names. thats it

Comment: `os.listdir(dir_loc)` will give you the all the file NAMES. It does not give you the actual files to manipulate, read and write only their name. If you want to store the names you already have them in `list_of_dir` iterate through and write them to a csv or whatever your  second choice is. @TheProfiler Please read your question, I'm sure you can't even understand it let alone others. Please make sure that you're getting the point across.

Comment: you want to upload the contents of each file into a database?

Comment: I need the actual files

Comment: yes, thats it..

Comment: which database? what's in the files? you need to provide more information, this question is soooooo vague I'm going to vote to close until more information is provided in the post via an edit

Comment: Same, I've given you the code to read from the files in the directory, that way each iteration you'll have the actual file in the `temp_file` and you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: I have edited .

Comment: those are different kinds of files and need to be handled differently this is still too broad

Comment: i understand. thanks for the feedback

Comment: Thank you, now it's a little bit more clear, you want to store the filenames into a mongodb, someone will help you out.

Comment: No I want to store the actual file in mongodb

Comment: @eagle this seems to do the job, TheProfiler, awesome! Take care!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We list the **current** directory and print the contents *you can do some other action with the read file, i.e. manipulate*

```
import os

dir_loc = os.getcwd()
list_of_dir = os.listdir(dir_loc)


for file in list_of_dir:
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        temp_file = f.read()
    # Do somethin with the file, it's currently stored in a variable
    print(temp_file) # I used print
```

With **Pymongo**:

```
import os
import pymongo
import gridfs

dir_loc = os.getcwd()
list_of_dir = os.listdir(dir_loc)

# Pymongo
connection = pymongo.Connection("localhost", 27017)
db = connection.yourdatabase

# Create a GridFS object using a reference to the database in which to
# store the file(s).

gridFs = gridfs.GridFS(db)


for file in list_of_dir:
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        file_id = gridFs.put(f.read(), filename="my_file_name")
```

Comment: it is showing this error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app_2.py", line 10, in <module>
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:`

Comment: Please use a directory that actually has files, instead of `dir_loc = os.getcwd()` do `os.chdir(path)` where `path` is your custom path with files in it.

Comment: Same here, I reran the code it works without a nitch, try printing the  list_of_dir to see if you actually have files as I said, I'm pretty sure you don't. It would be giving you this error.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply store it to a `txt` file using this code:

```
with open("somefile.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write(str().join([filename+'\n' for filename in filenames]))
```